# Create Json array from mysql data

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need a bit of help, i have this code:

```
$arr = [
        "inventory_id" => 2937,
        "products" => [],
];
$q = $dbc->query("SELECT quantity,productId FROM `Products` LIMIT 1");

while ($rs = $q->fetch_assoc()) {
    $arr['products'][] =  [$rs['productId']  => ["bl_3369" => $rs['quantity'] ] ];

}
```

which is returning

```
{
   "inventory_id":2937,
   "products":[
      {
         "154801353":{
            "bl_3369":"10"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

and i need to return like this:

```
{
    "inventory_id": "2937",
    "products": {
        "154801353": {
            "bl_3369": "10"
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone helping me? I search everywhere but i don't see how to adjust array to get needed structure

Comment: `i need to return like this`...do you though, really? The first format is much easier for those receiving your data to work with. Named properties whose value is not known in advance are a pain in the backside. A simple array of the products is a much better idea.

Comment: I'd even go so far as to say that you should aim to produce `"products":[{ "id": 154801353, "bl_3369":"10" }]`. That's even easier to work with. Avoid arbitrary, unpredictable key names as much as you can.

Comment: @RiggsFolly i checked json_encode manual, but i can't figured it out how to arrange my arrays, if i'm answering a question make me a bad guy, sorry for that :)

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your advice, but not depends on me, i need to send some data from my db to an API and that's their structure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding an extra array layer with the `[]`. Change the code to this:

```
while ($rs = $q->fetch_assoc()) {
    $arr['products'][$rs['productId']] =  ["bl_3369" => $rs['quantity']];
}
```